# Hypervisor call hvc argument uasage

Tags: arm

How is the hvc(0) call argument, I have seen usually 0, used ?

If r0 is not used to pass this argument then how it is passed to hvc handler.

I have seen two implementations of hypervisor vector table, both are like

```
.align 5
__hyp_stub_vectors:
__hyp_stub_reset:   W(b)    .
__hyp_stub_und:     W(b)    .
__hyp_stub_svc:     W(b)    .
__hyp_stub_pabort:  W(b)    .
__hyp_stub_dabort:  W(b)    .
__hyp_stub_trap:    W(b)    __hyp_stub_do_trap
__hyp_stub_irq:     W(b)    .
__hyp_stub_fiq:     W(b)    .
```

e.g. in below link

https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/kernel/hyp-stub.S?id=refs/tags/v3.9-rc3#n206

I don't understand that why a hypervisor trap is always located at 6th position in vector table.

Now call to hvc(0) switches to HYP mode,saves CPSR to Hyp_SPSR and branches to hyp vector table. From vector table __hyp_stub_do_trap routine will be called, which is at 6th position.

Why this trap routine will be called why not routine e.g. at 4th location (if defined ) will be called ?

Thanks,
Pankaj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exceptions in ARM Aarch32 have a specific vector address depending on the type of exception. Like listed above, exception can be Reset, Undefined instruction, System call (SVC), Prefetch or Data abort, Hypervisor trap, interrupts.

This is the job of the exception handler to define why the exception happened. In case of an hypervisor trap, either due by HVC instruction or by an instruction or register trap, the same handler is called. The handler can then look at the Exception Syndrome (`HSR`), that will give information about the reason of the exception.

Concerning the parameter for HVC, this is not passed on r0, but directly encoded in the opcode of the instruction. The handler can use the Link Register (LR or R14) to find the instruction and decode it, or use the Syndrome register to find this information.

Comment: So there is only one kind of trap be generated in Hyp mode... is that the reason only one vector defined and only once function hvc.

Or it is possible to have more traps like software interrupt etc. and define its handler in the same vector table.

Comment: There are several trap sources, for example you can trap an access to a system register. But each time the entry point is the same offset location in the vector table, and this cannot be changed.